# NodeJS - Waiting For Function to Complete

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I hope someone can assist, I am learning NodeJS/Express.js and am struggling.

The code below outputs the contents of two variables, however there are times when the res.send command is initiated before the second function ('city2') has had time to complete. From what I have read online, I need to use an await command to allow the second function time to complete before the remaining code is executed.

Additionally, res.write does not seem to work, as I would like to enter headings before the variable is displayed - is there anything I would need to add extra to get res.write to work?

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thank you.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const https = require('https');
var peopleDB;
var peopleDB2;
var cityName;

app.get('/city/:query', city, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.query);
})

async function city (req, res){
    cityName = req.params.query;
    var url = 'https://asdf-mytest-app.herokuapp.com/city/' + cityName + '/users';
    
    const request = https.get(url, response => {

        let body = "";
    
        response.on('data', data =>{
            body += data.toString();
        });
    
        response.on('end', () => {
            const people = JSON.parse(body);
            JSON.stringify(people);
            peopleDB = people;
        });
    });
    await city2();
    res.send({peopleDB,
        peopleDB2});
}

async function city2 (req, res){
    cityName = req.params.query;
    var url = 'https://asdf-mytest-app.herokuapp.com/city/' + cityName + '/users';
    
    const request = https.get(url, response => {

        let body = "";
    
        response.on('data', data =>{
            body += data.toString();
        });
    
        response.on('end', () => {
            const people = JSON.parse(body);
            JSON.stringify(people);
            peopleDB2 = people;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things which needs to be worked on

1. There should be response send method invoked in get request, like below, hence nodeJS is waiting for the function

   app.get('/city/:query', city, (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params.query);
   res.send({});
   });
2. second, I assume you intended to call city method in 1st point and send a response like below

   app.get('/city/:query', city, async (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params.query);
   const data = await city();
   res.send({data});
   });
3. I can see city2 doing almost the same thing city1 is doing. if by any chance you need to call city2 post city1 is completed, you need to call await city2(); inside response('end') event.